# How to show Disabled combobox in the same color as enabled one?

Tags: combobox, javafx, readonly

I have a javafx application which essentially save a invoice in the database and prints it, which can be given to the customer.

Essentially it is form, which takes inputs and on pressing Save button saves the record and makes the form read only till it is printed by pressing Print button. However, disabling the Combo box, seems the only way to make it readonly and this is causing change of color and making them difficult to read when printed. I tried setting the combo box style as below but is not helping. Any suggestions?

```
   duration.setDisable(true);
   duration.setStyle("-fx-opacity: 1");
   duration.setStyle("-fx-text-fill: black");
   duration.setStyle("-fx-background-color: white");
```

Answer (score 4):

`setStyle()` is, as the name should suggest, a setter method for the style attribute of a JavaFX `Node`.

By calling this method three times in a row, only the last invocation has an effect as the previous ones get overwritten.

So if you want to apply all three styles you should write:

```
duration.setStyle("-fx-opacity: 1; -fx-text-fill: black;-fx-background-color: white");
```

But this is enough to display the `ComboBox` in its default state even if it is disabled:

```
duration.setStyle("-fx-opacity: 1;");
```

---

**Edit #1: Sample**

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    ComboBox<String> combobox1 = new ComboBox<>();

    ComboBox<String> combobox2 = new ComboBox<>();
    combobox2.setDisable(true);
    combobox2.setStyle("-fx-opacity: 1;");

    BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
    root.setPadding(new Insets(15));

    root.setTop(combobox1);
    root.setBottom(combobox2);
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

This will produce the following output with no visible distinction:

[image: Combobox samples]

**Edit #2 CSS**

I forgot the list-cells inside the `ComboBox`, so we need some more CSS to reset the opacity:

```
.combo-box-base:disabled,
.list-cell:disabled
{
    -fx-opacity: 1;
}
```

You will have to add this CSS rules to a css file and then to your Scene, for example:

```
scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
```

Comment: Thank you, part of the problem as you rightly pointed out was that setStyle was getting overwritten. However duration.setStyle("-fx-opacity: 1) is not solving the problem completely. It is better than before, but it still looks greyed out. My guess is something which holds the combo box need to be modified.

Comment: Edited my answer with a sample and a screenshot of the output.

Comment: Hi Eckig, I thank you for the effort who are taking to help me solve this problem. I think the issue is with the font. Below is the app screen. The Membership Type (couple) is enabled while Duration and Membership Type (New) are disabled. I am attaching the screenshot below

Comment: Here is the link for the image http://i62.tinypic.com/2088xli.jpg I am too new to post a image on stackoverflow :(

Comment: Well, without a complete code example we can not find the source of that issue. But it is most certainly anywhere in your code, because my MCVE works.

Comment: You should not post additional code as answer, instead edit your question and insert it there. I edited my answer to complete the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The below code should simulate the problem

```
 public class JavaFXApplication8 extends Application {

 private ObservableList<String> comboboxdata = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

@Override
 public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

ComboBox<String> combobox1 = new ComboBox<>();

comboboxdata.add("Monthly");
comboboxdata.add("Quarterly");
comboboxdata.add("HalfYearly");
comboboxdata.add("Yearly");
combobox1.setItems(comboboxdata);
combobox1.getSelectionModel().select("Yearly");


ComboBox<String> combobox2 = new ComboBox<>();
combobox2.setItems(comboboxdata);
combobox2.getSelectionModel().select("Yearly");
combobox2.setDisable(true);
combobox2.setStyle("-fx-opacity: 1;");

BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
//    root.setPadding(new Insets(15));

root.setTop(combobox1);
root.setBottom(combobox2);
Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);
primaryStage.setScene(scene);
primaryStage.show();
}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

}
```

THIS IS HOW I SOLVED PROBLEM. Instead of disabling the Combobox, I have removed all the items from Combobox which I am not interested in. Once the user does what he needs to do, I have reinitialized to take the items back into Combobox. Dirty solution, but it works.

```
 public class JavaFXApplication8 extends Application {

 private ObservableList<String> comboboxdata = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
 ComboBox<String> combobox1 = new ComboBox<>();
 ComboBox<String> combobox2 = new ComboBox<>();

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {


setEnableMode();
BorderPane root = new BorderPane();


root.setTop(combobox1);
root.setBottom(combobox2);
Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);
primaryStage.setScene(scene);
primaryStage.show();

setPrintMode();
 }


 private void setPrintMode() {


   String temp = combobox2.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
   combobox2.getItems().removeAll(combobox2.getItems());
   combobox2.setValue(temp);

 // {Do what you have to do here}
  setEnableMode();  

}

private void setEnableMode() {  addComboData();  }

private void addComboData() { 
comboboxdata.add("Monthly");
comboboxdata.add("Quarterly");
comboboxdata.add("HalfYearly");
comboboxdata.add("Yearly");
combobox2.setItems(comboboxdata); 
combobox1.setItems(comboboxdata); 

 }
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

 }
```